# Why am I receiving a SQL Insert procedure ERROR. Msg 60060?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, raiseerror

I have the following query and error.  Why am I receiving this error? I found nothing online via Google.

MSSQL query:

```
INSERT INTO [CEPrekyba].[dbo].[BK1$REFGoodUnit]
([GoodCode],[UnitCode],[UnitName],[IsCommon]
,[IsAccount],[Rate],[IsPack],[IsInteg]
,[IsSize],[Lenght],[Height],[Width]
,[Weight],[GrossWeight]
,[IsReusable],[ManualInserted])
VALUES ('530162','VNT','Gamintojas','1',
'1','1,00','0','0',
'0','0,00','0,00','0,00',
'0,00','0,00','0','1')
```

Error message:

```
Msg 60060, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_sRaiseError, Line 13
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Comment: Look in the trigger. It says you right there in the last line :)

Comment: Error "60060" is a user defined error number, so it's being thrown explicitly by a Trigger on that table.